# I want to know if these sentences make sense?

Tags: grammar

I want to know that this sentence below makes sense. If it makes sense, what is the meaning of this sentence?

"This blew my mind no wonder some women are crazy and in pain."

[image]

Comment: What specific part of the (badly-written, *appallingly* punctuated) text is causing you problems? Idiomatic [blow your mind](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/blow-your-mind) is easily found in online dictionaries, as is exclamatory [no wonder](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/wonder_2?q=no+wonder). If your question is actually "proofreading", it's Off Topic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers this also raises the question of how we manage "culturally insensitive" questions.  I don't have a problem with the *intent* of this, but the phrasing is, as you say, appalling.

Comment: @Andrew: I'm no biologist, so I wouldn't know if period pain is in any way caused by the "swelling" as such. It's not like we all go around clutching our distended stomachs after drinking a small glass of water - which is about the same *change in size of an internal organ*. But what do I know? If it's *red*, it's probably sore.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I'm more put off by the use of "crazy" here to describe menstruating women.

Comment: @Andrew: I'm not really a big fan of ***crazy*** (seen too many Hollywood movies where the hero says "You're crazy!" to the bad guy). It's probably true that younger *native* speakers use it a lot anyway, but I also have the feeling that non-native speakers *overuse* it even more. Perhaps because unless and until they know a reasonable number of idiomatic alternatives for the possible senses (wacky but fun, mentally deranged / enraged, etc.) they just stick with ***crazy*** for everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image above is not following the rules of Standard English.  I'm not sure if there is a technical term for the specific dialect the author is using, but it is fairly common in online communities.  Many of the conventions of this dialect evolved from texting, where punctuation/capitalization or even entire words may be omitted if the author believes they are clearly implied through context.  This is also used for effect, to indicate speed or indifference.  Consider the following:

> 1) I don't know if I will be going.
>
> 2) don't know if I'm going

The second sentence is jarring to people expecting Standard English, but conveys a casual and younger attitude.  In communities where this kind of casual speech is common, using proper grammar makes you sound over-formal and intense.  Number 1 is texting to one's parents;  Number 2 is texting your friends.

Given that, we can look at the sentence and add in the implied punctuation to get a result closer to Standard English:

> This blew my mind [.] No wonder some women are crazy and in pain.  A replica of a uterus and the red is a replica of a uterus while on your period. This is crazy talk [!]  No wonder we feel bloated [.]

There are two unusual phrases here as well.

> This blew my mind.

This is "blew" as in "blew a gasket", to experience a catastrophic mechanical failure.  When your mind is blown, you are so shocked that you can no longer think rationally.  For example, seeing someone perform a really good magic trick might lead you to exclaim "Well, that blew my mind!  How did he do that?"

> This is crazy talk!

"Crazy talk" is the sort of thing that a crazy person would say, something unexpected and unbelievable.

If we rephrase the text with that in mind, it makes a little more sense:

> This is shocking.  No wonder some women are crazy and in pain.  A replica of a uterus and the red is a replica of a uterus while on your period. Unbelievable! No wonder we feel bloated.

As we said before, this is not Standard English, and is certainly confusing to a non-native speaker.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation~ I clearly understood.I swear that you are specialist in English